# Javascript show element if result is not null or hide elements if result is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can anybody suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

I have a div with id="profGroup-section" and have javascript function that check if integer field levelId has value or is null in database.
If levelid has a value I want to show div with id="profGroup-section", else if levelid is null then I want to hide div with id="profGroup-section".

I tried different approaches, but when levelid has value then I successfully show div, but I can't manage hide the div.

Thank You in advance...

Here is my code:

```
checkLevelDegree: function (serviceId) {

        var levelId;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Sale/GetServiceByID/",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: JSON,
            data: { serviceId: serviceId },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#profGroup-section").hide();
            },
            success: function (result) {

                levelId = result;
            },
            complete: function () {

                if (levelId === null || levelId === '') {

                    $("#profGroup-section").hide();

                    return;
                }
                else {
                    $("#profGroup-section").show();
                }
            },
            error: function () { }
        });
    },
```

Comment: why define `levelId` above? just have all of your code in the `success` callback and use `result` to determine whether to hide or show the div.

Comment: @r3wt I also tried that, but when debugging I have result = {levelId: null}, but the code is not compared here if (levelId === null || levelId === '') , instead always goes to else

Comment: there's your problem. `result` is an object, and you are checking if its a string or null. you have a bad assignment, change `levelId=result` to `levelId=result.levelId`

Comment: @r3wt Thank You very much for your help. That was the solution. Thanks again...